# Android - OpenGL ES 2 - Display video on vertices (SurfaceView)

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

Right now I use a SurfaceView to display images on vertices via OpenGL ES 2.0. 
I can't use a GLSurfaceView, since I want to manage myself the OpenGL contexts. 
I also use an offscreen Surface to encode a video of my OpenGL scene with MediaCodec.

The loading of images is in Java, but the draw calls are done in C++ (NDK).

The next step is to also display videos (from a file) on the vertices. So I guess I need to load every frame of the video (decoding), and do the same as images (put the image on vertices). But I don't know how to retrieve the frames of the video file, as Bitmap or GLint ? Is this possible or are there different solutions possible ? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html).  The purpose of SurfaceTexture is to take whatever is sent to its Surface and make it available as a GLES texture.

You can find an example of displaying a live camera feed on a GLES rect in [Grafika's](https://github.com/google/grafika) "texture from camera" Activity.

You don't say what the source of your decoded video is, but so long as it can send its output to a Surface the whole thing is fairly efficient -- frames are passed around by handle, not copied.  The alternative is to decode the video frames, convert YUV to RGB if necessary, and upload each frame with `glTexImage2D()`.  That will be much slower.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your answer. If I understand correctly, I can retreive the OpenGL textures from a SurfaceTexture (associated with a OGL context). But what I don't understand is how to provide the SurfaceTexture the frames of a video file.

Comment: Actually I've followed this example :

https://community.arm.com/thread/4068

And just added SetDataSource to the mediaPlayer (using a video file of course) and it works ! Thank you !